# Reopen closed window in Spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, window

How can I reopen a closed window in Spacemacs? Something like `Cmd-Shift-t` in Chrome.

I open a window using `SPC w s` and delete it with `SPC w d`, but I don't know how to reopen one that I've closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SPC w u` to undo changes to your windows, including reopening closed windows.

It runs `winner-undo`. Hit `SPC w U` for `winner-redo`.